# MonoGame loading a png file

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm trying to reference a png file in my code. In the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio I added the item to a folder called "Content" which is in the default "MonoGameWindowsApplication1" folder.

I've tried:

```
Texture2D background = Content.Load<Texture2D>("background");
```

and

```
Texture2D background = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Content/background");
```

but they both come back as null. How can I get a reference to the image?

Here's a screenshot of Visual Studio if that helps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj86s.jpg

Comment: I'll post this as an answer so you can mark it as solved.

Comment: I've already asked a simular question. this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69610612/monogame-not-drawing-png-images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution that looks to be related to your problem can be found **[here](http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/360681)**. You need to change `Content/background` to a 24 or 32 bit color format.

Comment: By the way, 24 bit color format does not work, so it must be in 32 bit color format!